# How to select data where id from a string ids?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i have two tables, TABLE1 with two columns (EID and NAME), TABLE2 with two columns (CID and E_LIST). Now, i want to select data from TABLE1 with EID from E_LIST of TABLE2, but seem it's not working.

```
EID NAME
E01 GREEN
E02 BROWN
E03 BLACK
E04 APPLE
E05 FOOD
E06 FISH

CID E_LIST
C01 E02,E05,E06
C02 E01,E02,E03

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE EID IN (SELECT E_LIST FROM TABLE2 WHERE CID ='C01')
```

Can you tell me what's mistake in here and give me solution about this. Thank you.

Comment: not working means, are you getting any exception? I Hope you are not getting results. Bcoz  E_LIST contains the data with comma. so you have to split and check.

Comment: @Srinath , not get data although no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [**string split function**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Split-function-in-SQL-Server-Example-Function-to-Split-Comma-separated-Delimited-string-in-SQL-Server-2005-2008-and-2012.aspx) like in the link. There are other better functions.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE EID IN (SELECT Item 
                                  FROM dbo.SplitString(SELECT TOP 1 E_LIST FROM TABLE2 WHERE CID ='C01'))
```

Comment: There are much better ways to split a delimited string than `While` loop

Comment: nice collection of functions in your link..bookmarked. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Stop storing comma separated values in single column. Have individual rows for each `CID` and `E_LIST` combination. Data retrieval will be much easier

Now coming back to the question, you need a split string function to do this

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE1
WHERE  EID IN (SELECT cs.split_items
               FROM   TABLE2 t2
                      CROSS apply Udf_splitstring(t2.E_LIST, ',') cs
               WHERE  t2.CID = 'C01')
```

Create one from here [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

I prefer the tally table method

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Udf_splitstring
(
   @List      NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
   WITH cteTally(N)  AS 
   (
       SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))+1) Number-1 
          FROM dbo.Numbers ORDER BY Number
   ),
   cteStart(N1) AS 
   (
       SELECT t.N+1 
          FROM cteTally t
          WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0)
   )
   SELECT split_items = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, 
      ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List, s.N1), 0) - s.N1, 8000))
   FROM cteStart AS s;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query compares an EID with a list of EIDs. You can solve the problem by doing a join instead of a subquery and using `like` assuming that one EID can't be a substring of another one.

Answer (score 0):

Use Left Join query. It will easy for you